# MKMapKit on iOS 6 and Google Maps on older devices

Tags: iphone, ios5, rubymotion

I'd like to show maps on iOS 6 by using `MKMapItem` but I'd also like to use Google Maps for older iOS versions.

When I test my solution on iOS 5.1 I have this error

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving
```

This is my code :

```
if Utils.older_than_ios6?
    url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=#{@party.place.location[1]},#{@party.place.location[0]}&daddr=#{@party.place.location[1]},#{@party.place.location[0]}"
    App::open_url(url)
else
    address_dictionnary = ({kABPersonAddressStreetKey: @party.place.street, kABPersonAddressCityKey: @party.place.city,kABPersonAddressZIPKey: @party.place.postal_code})
    place = MKPlacemark.alloc.initWithCoordinate(@coords, addressDictionary: address_dictionnary)
    mapItem = MKMapItem.alloc.initWithPlacemark(place)
    mapItem.name = "#{@party.name}"
    options = ({
        MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving
    })
    mapItem.openInMapsWithLaunchOptions(options)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/Reference/Reference.html) shows that `MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving` is available only on iOS6+.

And just to be sure, did you add MapKit to the list of frameworks in your Rakefile ?

Comment: He would get errors about MKPlacemark and MKMapItem if he hadn't added MapKit.